# Deploying App on Ropsten or any Test Network

Tags: truffle, testnets, ropsten, ethereumjs, ganache

I have a web3.js application which uses truffle and interacts with smart contracts deployed on Ganache.
How do I deploy my smart contract on a Test Network and interact with it through my application?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to install MetaMask and chose the network you're willing to test on . then you need to connect to MetaMask. it will automatically go on the test network you have chosen. read the [Metamask documentation](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/) and learn how to connect in [here](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it (tested with web3.js v1.2.1):

```
const fs   = require("fs");
const Web3 = require("web3");

const MIN_GAS_LIMIT = 100000;
const CFG_FILE_NAME = "SomeFile.txt";
const NODE_ADDRESS  = "YourNodeURL";
const PRIVATE_KEY   = "YourPrivateKey";
const ARTIFACTS_DIR = __dirname + "/RelativePathToYourBinAndAbiFolder";

function get() {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(CFG_FILE_NAME, {encoding: "utf8"}));
}

function set(record) {
    fs.writeFileSync(CFG_FILE_NAME, JSON.stringify({...get(), ...record}, null, 4));
}

async function scan(message) {
    process.stdout.write(message);
    return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.once("data", function(data) {
            process.stdin.pause();
            resolve(data.toString().trim());
        });
    });
}

async function getGasPrice(web3) {
    while (true) {
        const nodeGasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        const userGasPrice = await scan(`Enter gas-price or leave empty to use ${nodeGasPrice}: `);
        if (/^\d+$/.test(userGasPrice))
            return userGasPrice;
        if (userGasPrice == "")
            return nodeGasPrice;
        console.log("Illegal gas-price");
    }
}

async function getTransactionReceipt(web3) {
    while (true) {
        const hash = await scan("Enter transaction-hash or leave empty to retry: ");
        if (/^0x([0-9A-Fa-f]{64})$/.test(hash)) {
            const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
            console.log("Invalid transaction-hash");
        }
        else if (hash) {
            console.log("Illegal transaction-hash");
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

async function send(web3, account, gasPrice, transaction, value = 0) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            const options = {
                to      : transaction._parent._address,
                data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
                gas     : Math.max(await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address, value: value}), MIN_GAS_LIMIT),
                gasPrice: gasPrice ? gasPrice : await getGasPrice(web3),
                value   : value,
            };
            const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
            const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
            return receipt;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            const receipt = await getTransactionReceipt(web3);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
        }
    }
}

async function deploy(web3, account, gasPrice, contractId, contractName, contractArgs) {
    if (get()[contractId] == undefined) {
        const abi = fs.readFileSync(ARTIFACTS_DIR + contractName + ".abi", {encoding: "utf8"});
        const bin = fs.readFileSync(ARTIFACTS_DIR + contractName + ".bin", {encoding: "utf8"});
        const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi));
        const options = {data: "0x" + bin, arguments: contractArgs};
        const transaction = contract.deploy(options);
        const receipt = await send(web3, account, gasPrice, transaction);
        const args = transaction.encodeABI().slice(options.data.length);
        console.log(`${contractId} deployed at ${receipt.contractAddress}`);
        set({[contractId]: {name: contractName, addr: receipt.contractAddress, args: args}});
    }
    return deployed(web3, contractName, get()[contractId].addr);
}

function deployed(web3, contractName, contractAddr) {
    const abi = fs.readFileSync(ARTIFACTS_DIR + contractName + ".abi", {encoding: "utf8"});
    return new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), contractAddr);
}

async function run() {
    const web3 = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS);

    const gasPrice = await getGasPrice(web3);
    const account  = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(PRIVATE_KEY);
    const web3Func = (func, ...args) => func(web3, account, gasPrice, ...args);

    let phase = 0;
    if (get().phase == undefined)
        set({phase});
    const execute = async (transaction, ...args) => {
        if (get().phase == phase++) {
            await web3Func(send, transaction, ...args);
            console.log(`phase ${phase} executed`);
            set({phase});
        }
    };

    const contract1 = await web3Func(deploy, "contract1", "MyContract1", [arg1, arg2, arg3]);
    const contract2 = await web3Func(deploy, "contract2", "MyContract1", [arg4, arg5, arg6]);
    const contract3 = await web3Func(deploy, "contract3", "MyContract2", []);

    await execute(contract1.methods.setSomeValue(123));
    await execute(contract2.methods.setSomeValue(456));
    await execute(contract3.methods.doSomeStuff(true));

    if (web3.currentProvider.constructor.name == "WebsocketProvider")
        web3.currentProvider.connection.close();
}

run();
```

Note that you need to define the following variables at the beginning of your script:

```
const MIN_GAS_LIMIT = 100000;
const CFG_FILE_NAME = "SomeFile.txt";
const NODE_ADDRESS  = "YourNodeURL";
const PRIVATE_KEY   = "YourPrivateKey";
const ARTIFACTS_DIR = __dirname + "/RelativePathToYourBinAndAbiFolder";
```

Alternatively, you can pass them to the script via command-line arguments, and read them via:

```
const MIN_GAS_LIMIT = process.argv[2];
const CFG_FILE_NAME = process.argv[3];
const NODE_ADDRESS  = process.argv[4];
const PRIVATE_KEY   = process.argv[5];
const ARTIFACTS_DIR = process.argv[6];
```

Then, in the main function (`run`) at the bottom of the script, you should implement your initialization scenario instead of my coding example:

```
    const contract1 = await web3Func(deploy, "contract1", "MyContract1", [arg1, arg2, arg3]);
    const contract2 = await web3Func(deploy, "contract2", "MyContract1", [arg4, arg5, arg6]);
    const contract3 = await web3Func(deploy, "contract3", "MyContract2", []);

    await execute(contract1.methods.setSomeValue(123));
    await execute(contract2.methods.setSomeValue(456));
    await execute(contract3.methods.doSomeStuff(true));
```

This script is designed to resume from the last point of execution (i.e., if previously aborted).

Comment: https://github.com/amoghmahesh14/Project
This is my code, can you please help me out on how to customize your solution for my Application? Currently the App uses Metamask